# Getting excel to put together split strings

Tags: string, excel, text, split

I'm trying to get excel to put together a series of text strings that haven't been formatted systematically, so that they end up split into different rows on a data sheet.

I'm aware this might've been solved elsewhere so sorry for that but I'm struggling to describe the issue, and I can't post images on it but basically it's

- Column 1 with a list of the entries, and
- Column 2 with text strings that are spread over 2 or more rows

Is it possible to write some kind of formula or macro that would be able to check the first column and then stitch together all entries in the second column going down until it found a new entry in the first column? I've got a feeling it might be possible using some sort of loop thing with index functions, but I've no idea where to start even.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Mike give this a ty

Sub appendValues()

'The sub is designed to loop through code and when ever there is a null value and column a it will take the value of what is in column B and appended to the row above it and delete the row.

Dim row As Integer

row = 1

'This code starts with row one but this can be changed at will.

Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(row, 2).Value = ""

'loop statement is designed to continue to Loop until there is a null value inside of you the value in the second column.

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(row, 1).Value = "" Then

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(row - 1, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(row - 1, 2).Value & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(row, 2).Value

Rows(row).Delete

Else

'else statement is needed because there is an implied looping by decreasing the total number of rows after the delete.

row = row + 1

End If

Loop

End Sub

```
    Sub appendValues()
'The sub is designed to loop through code and when ever there is a null value and column a it will take the value of what is in column B and appended to the row above it and delete the row.

Dim row As Integer

row = 1

'This code starts with row one but this can be changed at will.

Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(row, 2).Value = ""

'loop statement is designed to continue to Loop until there is a null value inside of you the value in the second column.

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(row, 1).Value = "" Then

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(row - 1, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(row - 1, 2).Value & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(row, 2).Value

Rows(row).Delete

Else

'else statement is needed because there is an implied looping by decreasing the total number of rows after the delete.

row = row + 1

End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Mike did this work for you??  or do you need more help?